# Is it possible to disable pylint in a line based on its contents?

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

With [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.1/) it's possible to disable coverage in lines that match a pattern by adding the "exclude_lines" flag to the configuration file:

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
```

I was wondering if the same thing is possible with pylint. I'm doing a project in django and many classes have a very small, inner "Meta" class that is not worth documenting, yet I keep getting the missing-docstring error on each of them:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Docstring """

    class Meta:  # pylint: disable = missing-docstring
        model = MyModel
```

So far I've been adding a `# pylint: disable: missing-docstring` directive in each of them, but this is a bit tiring and prone to error, so I was hoping a better solution, similar to coverage's, exists. Does it?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I doubt it's possible. It could be an interesting feature though. -- But considering your exact use case: I would recommend renaming those inner classes to something like `_Meta`. _Pylint_ would consider the class as _private_ and would not bother checking if there is a docstring.